# Rails - permit a param of unknown type (string, hash, array, or fixnum)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My model has a `custom_fields` column that serializes an array of hashes. Each of these hashes has a `value` attribute, which can be a hash, array, string, or fixnum. What could I do to permit this `value` attribute regardless of its type?

My current permitted params line looks something like:

```
params.require(:model_name).permit([
    :field_one,
    :field_two,
    custom_fields: [:value]
])
```

Is there any way I can modify this to accept when `value` is an unknown type?

Comment: you need params.require to prevent security holes when you use mass assignment. if you don't use mass assignment, you do not need the parameter checking. otherwise, if you use it, you need to specify your parameters exactly to prevent security holes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want can probably be done, but will take some work. Your best bet is this post: http://blog.trackets.com/2013/08/17/strong-parameters-by-example.html

This is not my work, but I have used the technique they outline in an app I wrote. The part you are looking for is at the end:

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new(user: { username: "john", data: { foo: "bar" } })
# let's assume we can't do this because the data hash can contain any kind of data
params.require(:user).permit(:username, data: [ :foo ])

# we need to use the power of ruby to do this "by hand"
params.require(:user).permit(:username).tap do |whitelisted|
  whitelisted[:data] = params[:user][:data]
end
# Unpermitted parameters: data
# => { "username" => "john", "data" => {"foo"=>"bar"} }
```

That blog post helped me understand params and I still refer to it when I need to brush up on the details.